# The named parameter 'semesters' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter

main.dart
`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Provider(
      create: (_) => LoginService(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => SplashPage(goToPage: WelcomePage(), duration: 3),
          '/welcomepage' : (context) => WelcomePage(),
          '/categorylistpage' : (context) => CategoryListPage(),
          '/selectedcategorypage' : (context) => SelectedCategoryPage(),
        }
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

`

selectedcategorypage.dart
`

```
class SelectedCategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyCategory? selectedCategory;
  final List<MySemester> semesters;
  const SelectedCategoryPage({
    Key? key,
    this.selectedCategory,
    required this.semesters,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

`

I tried to make the routs but for selectedcategory I have `required this.semesters` which I don't need a required to but without it I get this error: The parameter 'semesters' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. I don't know how to get around it

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter 'semesters' is not required, then just remove the 'required' tag
and make the variable nullable. Like:

```
 final List<MySemester>? semesters;
```

Full code:

```
class SelectedCategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyCategory? selectedCategory;
  final List<MySemester>? semesters;
  const SelectedCategoryPage({
    Key? key,
    this.selectedCategory,
    this.semesters,
  }) : super(key: key);
```